# Bootstrap-Select -- How to keep static title?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-select, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Simple question. My select dropdown is like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-container="body" data-title="Options" data-size="10" data-width="100%" data-selectedTextFormat="static" >  
    <option value="default">Test</option>
</select>
```

I want it, regardless of what is selected, to keep that title ("Options"). Even if I do this:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', "default");
```

I want it to stay with the title "Options". I tried, as you can see about, the `data-title` and `data-selectedTextFormat` attribute, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you saying that no matter what the user selects you want the value to be "Options"?

Comment: @CesarBielich Precisely

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Options](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/)

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data
>   attributes, append the option name to `data-`, as in `data-style=""` or
>   `data-selected-text-format="count"`

Your data attribute isn't correct, it should be `data-selected-text-format="static"`.

**Using Data Attributes**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-title="Options" data-size="10" data-width="100%" data-selected-text-format="static">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

**Using JavaScript**

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  selectedTextFormat: 'static',
  width: '100%',
  size: 10,
  title: 'Options'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ohh, I see now, the mistake was the wrong data attribute. Thanks!

Comment: @vanburen there is a way to show a different text when a selection is made? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default to always remain the same no matter what the user selects then you could just set the value of each `<option>` the same and change the title

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-container="body" data-title="Options" data-size="10" data-width="100%" data-selectedTextFormat="static" >  
     <option value="Options">Title1</option>
     <option value="Options">Title2</option>
     <option value="Options">Title3</option>
     <option value="Options">Title4</option>
     <option value="Options">Title5</option>
     <option value="Options">Title6</option>
 </select>
```

but I have no idea why you would want that.